# Django admin filter foreign key

Tags: object, filter, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have 4 class:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)


class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)

class Physic(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name=_('name'), null=True, blank=True,)
    lapropriete = models.CharField(_('property'), max_length=100) 


class UniteProperty2(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Material, verbose_name=_('name'))                                   
    nature_unit = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name=_('category'))                    
    choix = models.ForeignKey(Physic, verbose_name=_('properties'), null=True, blank=True, related_name='choix')
```

What I want to do is when I am selecting nature_unit in UniteProperty2 it shows only properties (in administration interface)
that belong to the current category '
(ex: if i select Mechanical, i will have 'Hardness vickers', 'young Modulus', Maximum stress' in the dropdown list 'choix')

in the admin.py file, I have

```
class UniteProperty2InlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UniteProperty2InlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choix'].queryset = Physic.objects.filter(
            name=self.instance.name)


class UniteProperty2Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UniteProperty2
    form = UniteProperty2InlineForm




class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   inlines = (UniteProperty2Inline, ..)
```

but it doesn't work...i have the error 'No exception supplied'  Exception Type: DoesNotExist

the problem is : name__name=self.instance.name

Comment: I have found a solution

Comment: It seems nice..You should write it as answer with the [github link](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Answer (score 0):

`self.instance.name` - in ur form refers to UniteProperty2 name - which is a Material obj

so try this

```
self.fields['choix'].queryset = Physic.objects.filter(
            name=self.instance.choix )
```

or for all options:
self.fields['choix'].queryset = Physic.objects.filter(
                name=self.instance.choix )